# Change an IISExpress site's physicalPath on the command line

Tags: powershell, appcmd, iis-express

What's the easiest way to accomplish this? I see there's lots of examples for appcmd relating to IIS proper, and using powershell for same, but I can't see an API of sorts for reconfiguring the `physicalPath` of a `<virtualDirectory/>` node for a given `/site`.

I guess I could load up the `applicationHost.config` with the App configuration classes, but seems pretty verbose.

I'm looking for a one-liner here really.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, turns out it's very simple. It's the same as IIS. You just need to use the appCmd from IISExpress instead;

```
"%ProgramFiles%\IIS Express\appcmd.exe" set vdir "www/" -physicalPath:d:\myProjects\www
```